# How to access a locator from a different file by passing values

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a locator file locator.py and have got a page element file App_page.py separately. Is there a way I can declare the locator in locator.py and call it from the page element file App_page.py by passing value to it. For Eg :
`the locator is DASHBOARD_CELL = (By.XPATH, "//*[@data-drop-position='" + a + ":" + b + "']")` and I need to pass values to `'a'` and `'b'` dynamically from App_page.py.

Currently I'm trying below in locators file

```
class DashboardLocators(object):
def dashboard_traverse(a,b):
 DASHBOARD_CELL = (By.XPATH, "//*[@data-drop-position='" + a + ":" + b + "']")
```

and in Page element file , i'm trying to call the locator using :

```
a = '0'
b = '3'
id = self.driver.find_element(*DashboardLocators.dashboard_traverse(a,b)).click(
     )
```

It's not working. Am i following the right approach? If not could someone please let me know whats the better approach for this. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never returned the value from the function

```
class DashboardLocators(object):
  @staticmethod
  def dashboard_traverse(a,b):
      DASHBOARD_CELL = (By.XPATH, "//*[@data-drop-position='" + a + ":" + b + "']") 
      return DASHBOARD_CELL
```

Comment: thanks but even after adding "return", nothing is happening :(

Comment: Ahh I missed something, please check now. You needed `@staticmethod` also

Comment: What is the error? I am assuming By.XPATH returns "xpath" as the value?

Comment: I'm not seeing any error. I'm basically trying to click an element using find_element_by_xpath and then click(). Using the above approach I'm not able to click the element.

Comment: Actually ignore my above comment please. It worked fine with the suggestion you gave. Thank you so much :)

Comment: Great. can you please make it as the accepted answer?